# Gitlab static mkdoc website does not work. What can be the reason for it?

Tags: gitlab, mkdocs

I want to include a Mkdoc into my gitlab repository. I followed the instruction on Mkdoc, but the website is not showing up. The error message ist displayed on the screenshot below.

I included the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the root file. This is the content:

```
image: python:latest
pages:
 stage: deploy
 only:
   - master
script:
   - pip install mkdocs-material
   - mkdocs build --site-dir public
artifacts:
 paths:
   - public
```

I also included the mkdocs.yml and the docs folder on root. Is there anything else I must do?

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Is this a typo ```mcdocs.yml ``` instead of ```mkdocs.yml```? I am not sure how crucial the name of .yml file is.

Comment: Thanks @Lilya. Thsi is a typo. I edited it. Thanks. But it is still not working.